# How to avoid Flow-type error on ES6 arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I am having trouble resolving a Flow-type warning

When this code block is checked

```
export const login = (email: string, password: string) => ({
  type: types.LOGIN,
  responseTypes: [types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, types.LOGIN_FAILURE],
  promise: (client: Client) => client.post('/auth/sign_in', { email, password }),
});
```

I receive the warning

> error  Unexpected parentheses around single function argument having a
>   body with no curly braces  arrow-parens

However, when I remove the parenthesis around `(client: Client)`, I receive the error

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

at the colon after `client`.

Changing the function to the following

```
export const login = (email: string, password: string) => ({
  type: types.LOGIN,
  responseTypes: [types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, types.LOGIN_FAILURE],
  promise: (client: Client) => { return client.post('/auth/sign_in', { email, password }); },
});
```

the returns the following warning:

> error  Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body                                          arrow-body-style

I'm a little confused at to what the correct syntax would be to fix this warning. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The error you get is from [eslint arrow-parens](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens) rule, not from flow.

You can resolve it by changing your eslint config or trying the [ES6 method syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions):

```
promise(client: Client) {
  return client.post('/auth/sign_in', { email, password })
},
```

Comment: Oh wow I feel dumb, I totally overlooked that it was an eslint error and not a flow error. Thanks. If you have a suggestion to fix this warning I would appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Happened to me also :) Edited; you can use the es6 method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your first function, you are wrapping the body in parenthesis when it should be braces.

```
export const login = (email: string, password: string) => { 
  type: types.LOGIN, 
  responseTypes: [
    types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, types.LOGIN_FAILURE
  ], 
  promise: (client: Client) => client.post('/auth/sign_in', { email, password }), 
};
```

You can also write it this way (without using the single expression shorthand.

```
export const login = (email: string, password: string) => { 
  type: types.LOGIN, 
  responseTypes: [
    types.LOGIN_SUCCESS, types.LOGIN_FAILURE
  ], 
  promise: (client: Client) => { return client.post('/auth/sign_in', { email, password }); }, 
};
```

Comment: Thank you jordan, but the function is wrapped in parenthesis so that it can return the object literal with the `type`, `responseTypes`,  and `promise` attributes. The problem is the value of the `promise` (the arrow function) gets the Flow error.

Comment: Ahhh, you are right. My apologies, I didn't study the question very well before answering.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the effort to help answer regardless